# How do I access the metadata of a BigQuery table if I can query the table but can't find the table in the explorer panel?

Tags: google-bigquery

I've seen the BigQuery table called `bigquery-samples.wikipedia_benchmark.Wiki100B` in tutorials and I can query this table, but I cannot find it when I search for it in the Explorer.

1. Why can't I find it?
2. How do I see the table's metadata (schema, details, etc.)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st for your search, not giving results for `bigquery-samples.wikipedia_benchmark.Wiki100B` or `bigquery-samples` .

you must understand that `bigquery-public` and `bigquery-samples` are treated differently .if you are login by pointing to your specific project ex. `https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=myProject=!1m0`

then in the search you are bound to `bigquery-public` and may be some others but search will not compute for type `bigquery-samples` for that you need to follow this link `https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?project=bigquery-samples` and from there all the content under `bigquery-samples` will be available to search through.

2nd point you asked about the meta data

for that please go through [get_information_about_search_indexes](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/search-index#get_information_about_search_indexes)

> Get information about search indexes
>
> You can verify the existence and the readiness of a search index by
> querying INFORMATION_SCHEMA. There are two views that contain metadata
> on search indexes. The INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEARCH_INDEXES view has
> information on each search index created on a dataset. The
> INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEARCH_INDEX_COLUMNS view has information on which
> columns of each table in the dataset are indexed.
>
> The following example shows all active search indexes on tables in the
> dataset my_dataset, located in the project my_project. It includes
> their names, the DDL statements used to create them, their coverage
> percentage, and their text analyzer. **If an indexed base table is less
> than 10GB, then its index is not populated, in which case
> coverage_percentage is 0.**

```
SELECT table_name, index_name, ddl, coverage_percentage, analyzer
FROM my_project.my_dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SEARCH_INDEXES
WHERE index_status = 'ACTIVE';

The results should look like the following:

+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| table_name  | index_name  | ddl                                                                                  | coverage_percentage | analyzer       |
+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------+
| small_table | names_index | CREATE SEARCH INDEX `names_index` ON `my_project.my_dataset.small_table`(names)      | 0                   | NO_OP_ANALYZER |
| large_table | logs_index  | CREATE SEARCH INDEX `logs_index` ON `my_project.my_dataset.large_table`(ALL COLUMNS) | 100                 | LOG_ANALYZER   |
+-------------+-------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+----------------+
```

i just try to go through the material available on the internet so if you found any thing wrong or having any suggestion to me ,i will welcome every suggestion from all the subject experts

Comment: feels good know :)